# Transparent swf not receiving mouse events in internet explorer

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer

I'm embedding a flash swf into an html page and setting wmode=transparent. I need this flash movie to still receive mouse over events. In Opera, Safari, Chrome and Firefox this works fine, the html background shows through, and the flash mouse over events are still received. (Sprites react to mouse)

In Internet Explorer however, the background shows through, but no mouse interaction is happening with the swf itself.

Anyone have any advice to work around this? I'm open to even changing my AS3 code to correct.

Thanks -

b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make hollow Sprites. Fill color in area and make alpha=0 for that color where u want transparency. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed, Flash will not react to mouse actions where there is nothing drawn. If something is drawn, even if the alpha is set to 0, Flash will take note of this when hit testing and thus will dispatch the mouse events.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't occur to me, I suppose due to the inconsistent behavior across browsers. FYI - I changed my mouse events from being attached to the stage directly, to being attached a a filled sprite with an alpha of 0 that covers the stage and it works as expected in IE as well as all others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting its position to absolute and cranking up the z-index?